# What happened when I create a public "www.google.com" record set in AWS route53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

As you know, `www.google.com` is an already registered domain name on the internet.

I'm wondering why I can create a public hosted zone with domain name as `google.com` without getting any error from AWS route53.

[image]

[image]

I've read the document [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome-dns-service.html). It looks like that the name server for .com TLD is not affected by my route53 configuration.

What's the mechanism of the internet that prevents me from affecting `www.google.com` domain?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that you just create an entry on the servers provided by [AWS route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/), but that doesn't mean that **google.com** will now use the records you just created.

The reasons for this is because **google.com** is using its own defined name servers, to check this give try to this command:

```
$ dig google.com ns +short
ns3.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
```

You indeed can query your serves and ask for the `www.google.com` record, for example:

```
dig @ns-1656.awsdns-15.co.uk www.google.com.
```

Based on the images you posted, it should return the IP you defined `123.123.123.123`

Notice the `@ns-1656.awsdns-15.co.uk` the [@](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/man.dig.html) it is specifying `ns-1656.awsdns-15.co.uk` as the server to query.

But by using your system [resolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) you should get the google's IP:

```
dig www.google.com
```

All this ends to how DNS resolution works, you indeed can do a full trace, for example, check the output of this command:

```
$ dig www.google.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.google.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       557714  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       557714  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
;; Received 449 bytes from 10.10.1.21#53(10.10.1.21) in 493 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 492 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(192.36.148.17) in 315 ms

google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
;; Received 168 bytes from 192.55.83.30#53(192.55.83.30) in 27 ms

www.google.com.         300     IN      A       172.217.23.164
;; Received 48 bytes from 216.239.32.10#53(216.239.32.10) in 20 ms
```

This is how a query recursively receives a response in a typical DNS resolution scenario: (taken from: https://ns1.com/articles/using-dig-trace)

1. You as the DNS client (or stub resolver) query your recursive resolver for google.com.

   `dig google.com +trace`
2. Your recursive resolver queries the root name server for google.com.

   `; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.google.com +trace
       ;; global options: +cmd
       .                       557714  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
       .                       557714  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
       ;; Received 449 bytes from 10.59.1.21#53(10.59.1.21) in 493 ms`
3. The root name server refers your recursive resolver to the .com Top-Level Domain (TLD) authoritative server.

   `com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
   com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
   ;; Received 492 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(192.36.148.17) in 315 ms`
4. Your recursive resolver queries the .com TLD authoritative server for google.com

   `google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
   google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
   google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
   google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
   ;; Received 168 bytes from 192.55.83.30#53(192.55.83.30) in 27 ms`
5. The .com TLD authoritative server refers your recursive server to the authoritative servers for google.com.
6. Your recursive resolver queries the authoritative servers for google.com, and receives 216.239.31.10 as the answer.

   `google.com.         300     IN      A       172.217.23.164
   ;; Received 48 bytes from 216.239.32.10#53(216.239.32.10) in 20 ms`
7. Your recursive resolver caches the answer for the duration of the time-to-live (TTL) specified on the record, and returns it to you.

[image]

Comment: Note also that *"What happens is that you just create an entry on* **4 out of the hundreds of** *servers provided by AWS route 53,"* which also explains why this can't be used to hijack DNS even if the domain in question is already using Route 53, and why Route 53 allows the creation of multiple hosted zones in the same account or different accounts for exactly the same domain -- the 4 servers assigned for a given domain will never be the same.  (Note also that this is not to say that your hosted zone only has 4 actual servers handling its traffic across the globe... Route 53 is Anycast.)